# How to prevent UnityEngine.Debug.Log writing multiple lines to ADB

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb, remote-debugging

I am using ADB to log in Windows PowerShell from a Unity built application running on a connected Android device.
I am only interested in my own message invoked in script from e.g. UnityEngine.Debug.Log("***## State set to SolvingAnchor***"), but Unity appends 8 lines to this message:

- .\adb logcat -s Unity -e "^[#]{2}" -m 1
- --------- beginning of crash
- --------- beginning of system
- --------- beginning of main
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293  8315 I Unity   : ***## State set to SolvingAnchor***
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293  8315 I Unity   : UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object,
  String, Object[])
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293  8315 I Unity   :
  UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293 
  8315 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
- 02-11 10:07:42.658 
  8293  8315 I Unity   :
  Assets.Scripts.TrackedImageHandler:SetState(State)
- 02-11 10:07:42.658
  8293  8315 I Unity   : Assets.Scripts.TrackedImageHandler:Update()
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293  8315 I Unity   :
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293 
  8315 I Unity   : (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h
  Line: 35)
- 02-11 10:07:42.658  8293  8315 I Unity   :

As seen in the output filtering on regex is not working as I would have hoped.
Is there a way to only print the message and skip the Unity generated redundant lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Project Settings > Player > Android > Other Settings > Logging set all Logging Types to **None** or **Script Only**.

This will keep the ADB logcat rather compact.

[image: Player Settings > Log Type]

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Stack Trace Logging setting of your project in the Console window's top-right-corner menu:

[image]

Setting it to "None" will make Unity omit all those extra stack trace lines. You can set it for Errors, Warnings, Logs etc separately, or change it for all types of messages under "All".

Comment: This is also a working solution, but I marked JeanLuc's answer, as it feels more "accessible"

Comment: should be **Accepted Answer** , I wasted 1 hour of googling finally found this.